# need help in Integrating the SponsorPay Offerwall

Tags: ios, fyber

I'm trying to implement Integration the SponsorPay Offerwall to my iOS application, but I can't understand how determine when user finished watching video and how many virtual coins he gained. In documentation I did not found solution :(

Answer (score 1):

When the user finishes watching the video the delegate you registered when initializing the `SPBrandEngageClient` instance will have its `brandEngageClient:didChangeStatus:` method invoked.

What you will be looking for to find out when the user finished watching the video is whether the status received by this method is `CLOSE_FINISHED`.

If you get `CLOSE_ABORTED` instead, that means your user has closed the engagement before watching the video completely.

All the statuses are defined and described in the `SPBrandEngageClientStatus` enum that you can find in the `SPBrandEngageClient.h` file. It's also described in the **Integrating_mBE_SDK.md** documentation file, on the table at the end of the section "Requesting and showing engagements".

Your delegate must conform to the `SPBrandEngageClientDelegate` protocol, defined in the same header file.

Here's an example of initialization of the `SPBrandEngageClient` instance:

```
_brandEngageClient =
    [[SPBrandEngageClient alloc] initWithAppId:@"YOUR_APP_ID"
                                        userId:@"CURRENT_USER_ID"
                                      delegate:self]; // <-- this is your delegate
```

And here's an example of your `brandEngageClient:didChangeStatus:` delegate method:

```
- (void)brandEngageClient:(SPBrandEngageClient *)brandEngageClient
          didChangeStatus:(SPBrandEngageClientStatus)newStatus
{
    switch (newStatus) {
        case STARTED:
            // Your user just started watching the engagement
        break;
        case CLOSE_FINISHED:
            // This is it! Your user finished watching the video
        break;
        case CLOSE_ABORTED:
            // Engagement was cancelled
        break;
        case ERROR:
            // Something prevented the engagement from working correctly
        break;
    }
}
```

#### Determining how many virtual coins the user gained

If your `brandEngageClient:didChangeStatus:` delegate method receives the `CLOSE_FINISHED` status notification you can safely assume that your user will receive a payout. Determining the size of this payout cannot be done instantly, for it takes some time for the server to process it. The current SDK implementation requires that you poll the server periodically until you get an earned amount greater than 0. For that purpose you can use the provided `SPVirtualCurrencyServerConnector` class. [Here's a guide to its usage with some example code](http://developer.sponsorpay.com/docs/mobile/ios/publishing/virtual-currency-system/) (in this guide the class is described as SPVirtualCurrencyServerConnect**ion** instead, but the process is the same).

When the coins do arrive, your user will see a little notification briefly appear on the screen with the amount they earned, unless you disable it setting your `SPBrandEngageClient` instance's `shouldShowPayoffNotificationOnVirtualCoinsReceived` property to `NO`.